# Xamarin Android onActivityResult setting imageview with their Camera Example

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

Question about the lifecycle of the activity in Xamarin Droid.  I was trying to follow the Xamarin tutorial on [taking photos](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app) but I ran into a couple of problems.  In the example it calls up the camera intent and then sets the imageview onActivityResult base on the activity's local file property.

Problem 1

The first problem I had was that the local file property that was set before calling the camera intent was always null.  I solved that by saving the property OnSaveInstanceState as a pacelable and then setting it on create

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
        outState.PutParcelable("photoUri", photoUri);

    }
```

The second problem I had was that the ImageView sometimes updated and sometimes didn't onActivityResult

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ImageLoader.Instance.DisplayImage ("file://" + this.photoUri.Path, photo);
    }
```

It lookes like it would sometimes run OnActivityResult, then OnCreate very quickly in sucession reseting whatever was set in the onActivityResult.  I duplicated the imagelodader code into the onCreate function and that seems to have worked.

My question is, that seems kinda sloppy, am I doing something wrong?  It seems pretty random how the onCreate fires sometimes when we come back from the camera intent and after the onActivityResult.  Is it because it's running out of memory and re-creating the activity?  Why doesn't the xamarin sample code work as-is, was it a mistake on their part that the _file local variable doesn't hold it's state?

Comment: What device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: 2.3 api level 10 on samsung galaxy s2

Comment: Did you in the original code change the imageview in the continutwith method of the camera image task. Xamarin is quiet strange with accessing UI on non ui thread. it does not crash (?????) but stops execution at that point. and sometimes it just works. using java eclipse you would definitely crash.

Comment: I thought about that so I used AndroidUniversalImage Loader which does not stop the UI thread and works asynchronously.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I just tried the recipe on a Nexus One running Android 2.3 and it worked fine. What is going on in your ImageLoader class? It's weird that OnCreate is firing right after OnActivityResult? What is in your ImageLoader? Could something be crashing the app (out of memory?), which Android then restarts?

Comment: even if I take out the imageloader code it still calls oncreate.  Could it be a very sensitive screen rotation trigger?